# How can I optimize this function get all values in a redis json database?

Tags: .net-core, redis, stackexchange.redis

My function

```
public IQueryable<T> getAllPositions<T>(RedisDbs redisDbKey)
        {
            List<T> positions = new List<T>();
            List<string> keys = new List<string>();

            foreach (var key in _redisServer.Keys((int)redisDbKey))
            {
                keys.Add(key.ToString());
            }

            var sportEventRet = _redis.GetDatabase((int)redisDbKey).JsonMultiGetAsync(keys.ToArray());
            foreach (var sportEvent in sportEventRet.Result)
            {
                var redisValue = (RedisValue)sportEvent;
                if(!redisValue.IsNull)
                {
                    var positionEntity = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(redisValue, jsonSerializerSettings);
                    positions.Add(positionEntity);
                }
            }
            return positions.AsQueryable();
        }
```

Called as

```
IQueryable<IPosition> union = redisClient.getAllPositions<Position>(RedisDbs.POSITIONDB);
```

Where `Position` is a simple model with just a few simple properties. And `RedisDbs` is just an enum representing an int for a specific database.  With both this application and the redisjson instance running locally on a high performance server, it takes two seconds for this function to return a database with 20k json values in it.  This is unacceptable for my specific usecase, I need this to be done in the maximum of 1 second, preferably sub 600ms.  Are there any optimizations I could make to this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm convinced the problem is with the KEYS command.
Here is what is written about [Keys](https://redis.io/commands/keys/) command in redis.io:

> **Warning**: consider KEYS as a command that should only be used in production environments with extreme care. It may ruin performance
> when it is executed against large databases. This command is intended
> for debugging and special operations, such as changing your keyspace
> layout. Don't use KEYS in your regular application code.

You can save the list of your json keys and then use them in your function instead of calling the keys command.

Comment: So I timed each operation, keys took 150ms which isn't great, but acceptable, but 

`var sportEventRet = _redis.GetDatabase((int)redisDbKey).JsonMultiGetAsync(keys.ToArray());`

took 1500ms.  However, I can't find another alternative to this.

Comment: I see, it really sounded strange to me because 2 seconds is a lot of time even for the Keys command.

about the long operation, why do you have to reconnect to Redis every time you call the function?
What about making this function an extension method?
like this: 

`public IQueryable<T> getAllPositions<T>(this IDatabase db)
{
...
}`

And so you can call the command like this:
`var sportEventRet = db.JsonMultiGetAsync(keys.ToArray());`

Comment: I am not making a new connection everytime.  `_redis` is a `IConnectionMultiplexer` which is meant to be used like I am using it, you are not suppose to be storing `_redis.GetDatabase((int)redisDbKey)` as a variable. The keys command is only taking 150-250ms, 

`var sportEventRet = _redis.GetDatabase((int)redisDbKey).JsonMultiGetAsync(keys.ToArray());` is taking 1500ms